# Testing redirect after clicking

Tags: reactjs, redux, integration-testing, react-testing-library

I'm writting an integration test using react-testing-library, and I'm facing a problem: after clicking in a button I should be redirected to another page, but this isn't happening.

The test itself:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mockStore, renderWithRedux, screen } from 'tests/support/TestUtility';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import nock from 'nock';
import App from 'views/App';
import { STARTING_STORE } from 'tests/support/fixtures/startingStore';

it.only('test example', () => {
  const store = mockStore(STARTING_STORE);

  renderWithRedux(<App />, store);

  userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Comprar moeda' }));

  screen.debug(); // No errors, it shows me the same page I was before the click 
});
```

My `TestUtility` from where I export the `renderWithRedux`:

```
import React from 'react';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';

export const mockStore = (state) => {
  const middlewares = [thunk];
  const createStore = configureStore(middlewares);

  return createStore(state);
};

export const renderWithRedux = (component, store = {}) => {
  const history = createMemoryHistory();

  return {
    ...render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>{component}</Router>
      </Provider>
    ),
    store,
    history
  };
};

export * from '@testing-library/react';
```

The `<App/>` I'm rendering at first:

```
const App = ({ location }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      {location.pathname.match('/shopping-cart/') ? null : <ShoppingCartInfo />}

      <Switch>
        <Route exact={true} path={RouteEnum.Home} component={HomePage} />
        <Route
          exact={true}
          path={RouteEnum.Login}
          component={LoginPage}
          location={location}
        />
        <Route exact={true} path={RouteEnum.Signup} component={SignupPage} />
        <Route
          exact={true}
          path={RouteEnum.ResetPassword}
          component={ResetPasswordPage}
        />
        <Route path={RouteEnum.Currency} component={CurrencyPage} location={location} />
        <Route path={RouteEnum.CorrespondentShop} component={CorrespondentShopPage} />

        <PrivateRoute
          path={CheckoutRouteEnum.PrivateInfos}
          component={PrivateInfosPage}
        />
        <PrivateRoute
          path={CheckoutRouteEnum.DeliveryMethod}
          component={DeliveryMethodPage}
        />
        <PrivateRoute path={CheckoutRouteEnum.Payment} component={PaymentPage} />
        <Route path={CheckoutRouteEnum.ShoppingCart} component={ShoppingCartPage} />

        <PrivateRoute
          exact={true}
          path={MyAccountRouteEnum.OrderTracking}
          component={OrderTrackingPage}
        />

        <PrivateRoute path={MyAccountRouteEnum.MasterOrder} component={MasterOrderPage} />

        <PrivateRoute
          exact={true}
          path={MyAccountRouteEnum.PrivateInfos}
          component={UpdatePrivateInfosPage}
        />

        <PrivateRoute
          exact={true}
          path={MyAccountRouteEnum.Documents}
          component={DocumentsPage}
        />

        <PrivateRoute
          exact={true}
          path={MyAccountRouteEnum.UpdatePassword}
          component={UpdatePasswordPage}
        />

        <Route exact={true} path={RouteEnum.Error} component={ErrorPage} />
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>

      <ToastsContainer />

      <Spacer />
    </>
  );
};
```

And the page from where I get the button where the `click` is performed:

```
class HomePage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <br />
        <a role="button" href={RouteEnum.Currency.replace(':slug', 'dolar')}>
          Comprar moeda
        </a>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Any thoughts on why the redirect action isn't happening?

Comment: Try to change your `<a href="...">` by a `<Link to="...">` (from React Router)

Comment: Thanks, @Freez. I don't understand why it didn't work with `<a>`, but `<Link>` solved the problem.